# How to add data from database into object in php for temporary using while loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am new in php . I have the following code to retrieve categorytype data from database?. I want to add them into php object for temporary using while loading page. First, I want to load all predefined data, then i will use it when i click function. Could you enlighten me how to create it

categoryDao.php

```
namespace category;

use Exception;
use PDO;

class categoryDao{

    public function categorytype(PDO $connection){

        $conn = $connection;
        try {

            $conn = $connection;

            $sql="SELECT * FROM `tb_category` WHERE id != parent_id;";
            $categorytype = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $categorytype->execute();
            $data1 = array();
            while (                     
                $result = $categorytype->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $data1[] = $result['id'];
                    $data1[] = $result['c_name'];    
              }             

              return $data1;

        } catch (Exception $e)  {
            echo $e;
            throw $e;    
        }
    }
}
```

categoryservice.php

```
use category\categoryDao;

require '../dao/categoryDao.php';
require 'Dao.php';

class categoryService{
    public function categorytype(){

        $dao = new Dao();
        $conn= $dao->connect();
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $categoryDao = new categoryDao();
        //$data1 = array();
        $data1=$categoryDao->categorytype($conn);

        return $data1;
        $dao->disconnect($conn);
    }
}
```

categorytypecontroller.php

```html
 <?php 





require '../service/categoryService.php';


require '../service/categoryService.php';


$categoryname = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['category']));
$category = new  categoryService();
//$ctype = array();
$ctype = $category->categorytype();

$return["json"] = json_encode($ctype);

echo $return["json"];
```

Head.php

```js
function categorytype() {
     //var hosname =window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname +  window.location.pathname;
     var hosname1 = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname+ "/servicegateway/sgw/modules/controller/categorytypecontroller.php";
     alert (hosname1);
     //var ur = hosname + "/modules/controller/categorycontroller.php";
     
      $.ajax({
        url:hosname1 , //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success:function(data1){
            alert(data1);  
            var  obj =data1;
           // var leng = Object.keys(obj).length; 
           
            
            var areaOption = "<option value=''>Select Category </option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                areaOption += '<option value="' + obj[i] + '">' + obj[i] + '</option>'
            }
            $("#c_type").html(areaOption);                     
        }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.  If you want the data to be an array of records, you'll probably want to change this part:

```
while ($result =  $categorytype->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $data1[] = $result['id'];
  $data1[] = $result['c_name'];
}
```

as that is putting all the fields, one after the other, into a normal array.

```
while ($result =  $categorytype->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $data1[] = array(
    'id' => $result['id'],
    'c_name' => $result['c_name']
  );
}
```

That will create a small associative array of the id and name fields and put it into another array, with the other records.  PHP associative arrays will turn into Javascript objects when sent via ajax.

Then, in Javascript, you'll want to make use of those objects to create your options, so:

```
areaOption += '<option value="' + obj[i].id + '">' + obj[i].c_name + '</option>'
```

Comment: May I know How to put them all into object and retrieve them from ajax side? Thank you.

Comment: The code you have looks fine for that.  Your ajax options contain dataType:json, so the parameter to the success function (data1) should be an array of objects already.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: My program is okay now. I would like to know that every time I refresh the page, does it connect to database? Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Not in the code you have posted.  That just does any database stuff when the javascript function categorytype() is called.  However you might have other code in the rest of your page that loads from the database.  Can't tell!